# React Native DrawerLayoutAndroid ref not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, drawerlayout

This is what i have so far

```
  <DrawerLayoutAndroid
    ref={'drawer'}
    drawerWidth={300}
    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
    renderNavigationView={() => {
      return navigationView;
    }}>
      <Navigator
        ref={'navigator'}
        initialRoute={initialRoute}
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
            routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#68758E', height: 50 }}
            />
        }
        configureScene={(route, routeStack) => {
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump;
        }}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
          console.log(this, this.refs);
          if (this.refs.appDrawer) {
            console.log(this.refs.appDrawer);
          }
          if (self.backButtonEventAdded === false) {
            BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
              if (navigator && navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
                  navigator.pop();
                  return true;
              }
              return false;
            });
            self.backButtonEventAdded === true;
          }
          if (route.id == 0) {
            return (
              <HomePage navigator={navigator} />
            );
          }
          if (route.id == 1) {
            return (
              <RingtonePage ringtone={route.ringtone} />
            );
          }
        }}
        />
  </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```

Now in the renderScene method of Navigator the first line logs `this` and `this.refs` `console.log(this, this.refs)`
When i inspect `this` in the chrome it has the proper refs set on it but the second `this.refs` is and empty object. Why is that ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understood what's precisely is your problem... What's the precise error-message ?

Here is an example of a DrawerLayoutAndroid which works great...

`<DrawerLayoutAndroid
                drawerWidth={300}
                ref={'drawer'}
                navigator={Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump}
                drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Right}
                renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
                <Navigator
                    film={this.props.film}
                    configureScene={(route) => {
                            transition = Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump
                            transition.gestures = null}}
                    navigator={this.props.navigator}
                    initialRoute={{onRightButton: (() => this._openDrawer())}}
                    navigationBar={
                    <Navigator.NavigationBar style={{backgroundColor: '#246dd5'}}
                        routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
                        }
                        renderScene={() =>this.renderScene(this.props.film)}
                    />
</DrawerLayoutAndroid>`

and here is the function  for open it :

`_openDrawer:function() {
        this.refs['drawer'].openDrawer();
    },`

Hope this will help you :) !

Comment: the refs object is not available to me in this that you are using in _openDrawer method , which version of react-native are you using ? i am using 0.25

Comment: I'm using 0.2.0 ! Did you call your `DrawerLayoutAndroid` in your render Method() ?